# Parsing the sentences "Let's {go/go and/go to} try it."

Tags: parsing, catenative-verbs

> Let's go try it.

I know the above sentence is quite correct grammatically because I have heard it spoken on numerous occasions.

Could anyone please parse it for me?

Also, what's the problem with these versions of the same sentence (Or how are they different)?

> Let's go and try it.

> Let's go to try it.

Comment: I'm not convinced "Let's go try it" is in fact "correct". As with *You should **come visit** me soon* and *I'll **go see** what he wants,* I think strictly speaking those two verbs should be separated by ***and*** (or feasibly ***to*** or some other "linking" element). There are other English verbs that can quite naturally "concatenate" in this way *(Vaccinations **help prevent** illness, I don’t **dare fight** a gorilla,...)*, but mostly it's not really "valid" without ***something*** in between the two highlighted verbs.

Comment: Native speakers who don't know or care about formal syntax can easily identify "flaky" usages by considering what happens if they switch to ***past tense***. Even the sloppiest native speaker would never say [*We **went tried** his idea, but it didn't work*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143305/i-went-see-his-dog-in-american-english) (though the linking ***and*** might be very "unstressed" there). But presumably whoever asked that linked earlier question got suckered into thinking it *might* be valid because *he also* thought that *Let's **go try** his idea* was "valid".

Comment: @FumbleFingers— Thank you very much. What about the idiomatic expression _Go figure_? Shouldn't it be _Go and figure_ instead, then?

Comment: If you don't mind answering this small question as well, I would be thankful to you. What is with this construction _Many years later, as he faced the firing squad, Colonel Aureliano Buendía **was to** remember that distant afternoon when his father took him to discover ice._ " Why **was to** instead of, say **would**?

Comment: Yes, no-one would ever say *We **went figured** it out* - it's just that with Present Tense and Infinitive verb forms it's often "idiomatically acceptable" to discard the linking term (usually, ***and***). For your ***was to*** there's nothing really wrong with using ***would***. The choice makes a ***very subtle*** difference in terms of focusing on a "narrative reference time" (which "flip-flops" between the earlier "ice discovery" and the later "firing squad" time-frames). But if you can't easily see that difference for yourself (and you probably can't), it's not worth bothering about.

Comment: Thank you very much, @FumbleFingers! Yeah, you're right that I'm having trouble spotting the difference easily. And OED has compounded it for me: (_was to_) With infinitive: *Expressing an appointed or arranged future action; (hence also) expressing necessity, obligation, duty, fitness, or appropriateness.* Is this the meaning here? I don't think so. And does this sentence qualify as an example of prolepsis?

Comment: I think I was misled by your "catenative verbs" tag here. I don't care much about precise grammatical terminology, but since I know what *[con]catenation* means, I simply assumed your ***go try*** was an example catenative verb usage. Now I think not, but I haven't been able to find out what it ***is*** called. Well, actually, I'm quite sure your specific example is just a colloquial "ungrammatical" usage anyway, but I **dare say** there's more to it that that. Why is it ***perfectly okay*** to omit the infinitive marker in ***to** say* there?. I've no idea, but there must be other examples.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually I was referring to the _was to_ question. You have answered the main question nicely already! :)

Comment: *1: I am going home today = 2: I will go home today = 3: I am to go today.* The only real difference being that #3 there implies *someone else* was instrumental in deciding when I would go home (whereas the other two might simply reflect what ***I*** have decided to do).

Comment: In your "firing squad" example, telling us what the Colonel ***was to*** do actually puts the narrative focus quite firmly in the *earlier* time (the time of the ice trip, back when *thinking about that ice trip* while facing a firing squad was well and truly ***in the colonel's future***). The ***would*** version tends to slide the narrative focus forward towards that "future in the past" time when he was/would be facing / did face the firing squad.

Comment: @FumbleFingers— I understood what you said except for this: _The **would** version tends to slide the narrative focus forward towards that "future in the past" when he would be facing the firing squad._ So far so good. What do you mean by _when he was facing or did face the firing squad_, he **would** remember....? How could a writer project the "future in the past" using the verb forms _was facing/did face_?

Comment: The cited context is very definitely "future in the past" from our point of view *reading* it, because the context is a past tense narrative within which there's a reference to something that happened ***more recently*** than "narrative time" (so *within* the narrative, that firing squad episode still lay in the future, even though it was long ago by the time we're actually reading it)....

Comment: ... What I'm saying is that when we read about what that "earlier" incarnation of the Colonel ***was to do** [later]*, the narrative focus attaches very strongly to ***him at that time*** (with the firing squad well and truly in his future). But to me at least, talking about what he ***would do** [later]* tends to shift the narrative focus forward to that later time. But as I said, this is a very fine point, and it's unlikely everyone would recognise it even if it was explicitly pointed out to them. It's not a bulletproof distinction, by any means.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could these be an answer?

Answer (score -1):

They're all correct, but I'd suggest never using the third one, unless there was a convention called "Try It," and you were going to Try It lol. But the second one is just over using the word "and." Stick to simple.

Comment: No they're not.  "Let's go try it" is not grammatically correct, although it is in common use in American English.